# How to find duplicates of my own or arbitrary question

Tags: support, duplicates

How to know which questions are duplicate of my question. Is there any way to find which questions are marked as a duplicate of mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

1. You can create a query, or try to see if [there is an already existing one](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/173779/all-questions-marked-as-duplicates-of-your-own-questions), in the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/queries)
2. A less technical one would be to go into each question of yours, and check the linked questions in the right pane. **But**, they aren't necessarily duplicates. And If there were a lot of duplicates, it won't show all of them.

Comment: After some testing, I don't think that query behaves as expected